# difference between authorized_keys and known_hosts files?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

When it comes to the use of ssh service (client & server), I'm quite confused as to the use of these two files, :

- authorized_keys
- known_hosts

what's the difference between them? what are their similarities (if any)?which one's on the server-side and which one's on client-ssh?

any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

authorized_keys is a file that allows you to add ssh public keys of users that should be allowed to log into your server (the server in which the authorized_keys file lives) using key based auth.

known_hosts is a file that contains a list of keys from...known hosts that you have logged into.  These keys pair an IP address with a server's key to help prevent you from logging into an impersonated server. Usually these keys will be setup the first time you log into a host but you can also manually configure these if security is very critical in your environment.

Comment: do they both exist on the server side? Are they both are under `~/.ssh/` ?

Comment: They both exist on all machines that have openssh